# Dispatch custom Event to a JS object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a object Constructor that I want to dispatch a customEvent from. Then I want to listen to it from the instance of the object.
The code below is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish. Anyone know how or if this is possible.

```
    var example = new Example();
    example.addEventListner('customEvent', tempMethod);

    function tempMethod(event){
    console.log("event working = ", event.message);
    }

    function Example(){

   // dispatch and event from here.
this.dispatchEvent('customEvent', 'message hello');
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you're a little confused about how "classes" work in javascript ?

Comment: Why ? All I'm trying to do is dispatch an event from a JS object. As far as I'm aware there are no classes in JS ?

Comment: That's why I wrote it in quotes, but you're using the `new` keyword, which is commonly referred to as "classes", but what are you trying to create a new instance of, the function with the jQuery event handler, and how exactly would that work ?

Comment: Well, `addEventListner` is a typo, it's `addEventListener`, and a "class" object has no `addEventListener` method, DOM elements have event listeners ?

Comment: Ok forget the jquery button, it might be confusing. I just want to dispatch an event from the Constructor. And listen on the instance. I agree this might not be a full application situation but just trying to find out can it be done.

Comment: Again, plain objects do not have event listeners, if you create an instance of a function, that instance has no addEventListener or dispatchEvent, only DOM nodes have methods like that. You'll have to create your own listeners and dispatchers if you really need this.

Comment: @Chapsterj Since there's nothing in either jQuery or JavaScript API to support the interaface you're describing, you would have to implement `dispatchEvent` and `addEventListener` methods on the `Event.prototype` yourself and go from there. It really depends on your use case so it's hard to give a generic answer here, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to create an emitter from a plain object (or from your `Example` *instance*).

```
var emitter = $({});
$(button).click(function() {
  emitter.trigger('customEvent');
});
```

You could also use an emitter library like [energy](https://github.com/ryanve/energy) or [eventemitter2](https://github.com/asyncly/EventEmitter2).

```
var emitter = energy();
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  emitter.emit('customEvent');
}, false);
```

Without the button (as in your edited question) you can create your own `.on`, `.off`, and `.emit` methods on your `Example.prototype` or you can assign them from an emitter instance [like this](https://github.com/ryanve/ux/blob/0.0.0/ux.js#L128-L131).

Comment: Thanks ryanve I know how to use the jquery trigger I'm looking to see if it can be done without jquery.

Comment: @Chapsterj Gotcha. See those libs in my edit for ideas. It depends on what your trying to do.